# Trigger para Eliminar espacios en blanco de un campo

Tags: trigger

Necesito crear un evento para borrar los espacios en blanco del campo  "razsoc" , al crear o actualizar el registro.  desconozco como saber el id que se le agrego con incremento automático. Algo así pero para ambos procesos al insertar o actualizar dicho campo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: El código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Además, pon en las etiquetas a qué base de datos haces referencia: [trigger] no es una etiqueta descriptiva.

Comment: No es una buena idea lo que intentas hacer aquí. Me pregunto: ¿desde dónde se insertan/actualizan esos datos? ¿Por qué no limpias los datos allí, antes de insertarlos o actualizarlos? Programar un TRIGGER para esto es hacer que la base de datos trabaje dos veces con respecto a los datos, aparte de tener dicho TRIGGER ahí constantemente. Deberías garantizar la limpieza de los datos donde se recogen dichos datos. Esto no debería ser tarea de la base de datos.